# Mount a samba share as root using smbfs in fstab

Tags: samba, ubuntu, fstab, smbfs

I'm trying to mount a samba share using smbfs as root (on ubuntu-server), but every time I mount it it's mounted as `root:dialout`

Here is the fstab entry (line breaks added for presentation)

```
//192.168.1.68/mount_name /root/mount_point smbfs ¬
auto,username=user,password=pass,uid=root,umask=000,user,defaults 0 2
```

How can I make it mount as the root group?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the gid=root option to the options. Also, use the cifs client rather than smbfs, as that is more modern.

Answer (score 2):

//192.168.1.68/mount_name /root/mount_point smbfs ¬
auto,username=user,password=pass,uid=root,**gid=root**,umask=000,user,defaults 0 2